# How to order by certain part of a string?

Tags: sql, mysql

How to order by certain part of a string, assuming i have column `codes` which has values of the following format: LLL_NNN, example dGd_542.  How can i order by the second part of the string which is numerical?

Comment: LOL.  Tags added make my previous comment look dumb. They weren't there originally. Deleting previous comment.

Comment: In that case, I beg your pardon (didn't check the tag timing).

Comment: @David Stratton: Yes there were, but no prob :)

Comment: Yeah, I could have just been blind.  I usually don't need help to sound dumb.  Looks like you got good answers anyway!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to just extract [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) from your code.

```
order by SUBSTRING(codes, 4) asc
```

Comment: For last characters you can use minus values, for example if you want to order by last three characters,
order by SUBSTRING(codes, -3) asc

Answer (score 3):

use the `SUBSTRING` function

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(codes FROM 4)
```

On very large tables this can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

(First the obligatory comment on database structure)

It appears the you have two meaningful values encoded into the single column `codes`.  If at all possible you should refactor your database so those are separate columns.  The sorting problem then goes away.

(Now the answer using the existing database structure)

You can use an expression and order by that expression:

```
 SELECT c1, c2, c3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(codes, '_', 2) as code_value
    FROM table ORDER BY code_value
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood, this can solve your problem...

> select substring( field, 5, 7) as
>   field2 from db.table order by field;