# Rails 3 multiple default_scope alphanumeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default-scope

I have a column in my table that are codes. They are in the format of
`AAA-XXXX-YYY` where

- `AAA` is Alphabetical
- `XXX` is Numeric
- `YYY` is Numeric

I want to use an alphabetical sort on `AAA`, then numeric sort on `XXXX`, then numeric sort on `YYY` for my default_scope so when I index them they are sorted like that.

If I did an alphanumeric sort on the column I would end up with the following:

```
AAA-1000-1
AAA-1000-111
AAA-1000-2
BB-1000-12
BBB-1000-1
BCA-1000-1
C-1000-12
```

but 111 is bigger than 2 using a numeric sort.

EDIT:AAA is not fixed in length. So it could be "AA" or "BBBB" or "CCC". There has been mention of using SQL SUBSTRING but the position is not always set.

EDIT2: I probably should mention this sort needs to be done on a default_scope so when I access Object.all they are by default sorted this way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480703/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-array-in-ruby

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785424/how-to-order-by-certain-part-of-a-string for table sorting based on substrings in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['AAA-1000-1','AAA-1000-111','AAA-1000-2','E-3-3','E-2-3','CCCC-2-45']

arr.sort_by {|elm| "%10s%10i%10i" % elm.split('-') }

=> ["E-2-3", "E-3-3", "AAA-1000-1", "AAA-1000-2", "AAA-1000-111", "CCCC-2-45"]
```

Comment: How do I get this to run within default_scope. And how do I get the first section to sort alphanumerically. Meaning the following:  A, AA, BBB, C, D1, D1A, DA, DB3, DBB

Comment: And also a follow up, how about sorting by the middle section first, then first section, then third section? Thanks in advance!